# why will we have different results with splash and chrome accessing same website?

Tags: python, web-crawler, splash-screen

Why will we have different results with splash and chrome accessing same [website](https://flight.qunar.com/site/oneway_list_inter.htm?searchDepartureAirport=%E6%B7%B1%E5%9C%B3&searchArrivalAirport=%E4%BC%A6%E6%95%A6&searchDepartureTime=2017-09-27&searchArrivalTime=2017-09-30&nextNDays=0&startSearch=true&fromCode=SZX&toCode=LON&from=qunarindex&lowestPrice=null&favoriteKey=&showTotalPr=null&adultNum=1&childNum=0&cabinClass=)?

Comment: we found lost some cookie info we don not know the reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: These usually boil down to cookies / websites responding differently depending on your user-agent / javascript or browser quirks